# MYST/RIVEN and Quicktime Video Integration

Tags: methodology

How was Quicktime video integrated into the MYST series games? I was watching a Making of MYST video and noticed that they used a small green screen and for the sequels like Riven they continued to use a green screen but with a much bigger stage. How is it that they match up the video file and integrate it seamlessly into the game? I'm really curious as to how they did it with Riven, where full body actors actually move around with a greater degree of freedom.

My guess is that the video recording is an exact duplicate of a pre-rendered scene. When the player enters into a certain area where a movie is supposed to take place, the video is drawn onto the screen and played. After the video ends, the pre-rendered screen is drawn back to the screen that reflects the changes that took place in the video.

Any other ideas how it might have been done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't know where to find them anymore, but the Miller brothers made a lot of "making of" type stuff for Myst at least, and it is basically as you describe except with a heaping helping of manual effort and tweaking to make it look good.